# Calculate Distance Between 3D (NED) Geographic Coordinates (Lat, Long, Depth)

Tags: r, math, trigonometry

It is well known that the [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) is a useful mechanism in which to calculate distances between geographic coordinates.  Obviously, there are certain packages in R which provider further refinements; accounting for the ellipsoidal nature of the earth.

What I cannot find, however, is any method for finding the **straight-line distance between [NED coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system#Local_north.2C_east.2C_down_.28NED.29_coordinates)**: that is, **latitude, longitude and depth**.

This type of distance calculation is essential for research on events which occur deep under oceans, or under the earth's crust in general.

Is anyone aware of a method to assist with this type of distance calculation on a sphere? On the earth?  If not, does anyone have any ideas what the best trigonometric approach to this problem would be?

Comment: I would think there is no standard formula to do this - If I want to get from one side of a mountain to another, the "along the earth" distance would be far greater than the equivalent distance on a flat plane - even if in both cases the x delta, y delta and depth are the same.

Comment: @Chris I am not sure I see your point; there definitely is a solution.  With deep oceanography as well as geoscience there is a need to calculate the distance between two points deep below sealevel.  The terrain height is irrelevant.  The issue is one of mapping NED coordinators to a Cartesian 3D plane, then calculating the appropriate distance.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your request. Do you need straight-line distance? If you want the distance from walking along the floor, the local terrain becomes important

Comment: @Chris Yes, straight-line, keeping in mind that the NED coordinates are not  on the Cartesian plane.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linear distances are much easier to compute in a Cartesian coordinate system, so the first step is to convert your NED coordinates (i.e. long-lat-height) coordinates to some such system. In the open source world, PROJ4's "geocent" projection, which gives locations in meters in an orthogonal x-y-z coordinate system, is a good choice.

Simon Urbanek's [**proj4**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/proj4/index.html) package provides a good lightweight means of accomplishing that conversion. To demonstrate it's use, I'll write a little wrapper function that takes two points in NED coordinates and computes their separation in meters. (The one complication is that the `ptransform()` expects its latitude and longitude coordinate in radians; hence the divisions by `180/pi` in the function's first and second lines.)

```
library(proj4)
findDist <- function(x=c(0,0,0), y=c(0,0,0)) {
    x <- matrix(x/c(180/pi, 180/pi, 1), ncol=3)
    y <- matrix(y/c(180/pi, 180/pi, 1), ncol=3)
    xx <- ptransform(x, src.proj="+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84",
                        dst.proj="+proj=geocent +ellps=WGS84")
    yy <- ptransform(y, src.proj="+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84",
                        dst.proj="+proj=geocent +ellps=WGS84")
    sqrt(sum((yy-xx)^2))
}

## A sanity check. (Find distance between two points at 0°N 0°E, one on the
## surface and one 100m below the surface (i.e. at a height of -100m).)
findDist(c(0,0,0), c(0,0,-100))
## [1] 100

## Distance from North to South Pole
findDist(c(0,90,0), c(0,-90,0))
## [1] 12713505

## Diameter of the earth at its equator
findDist(c(0,0,0), c(180,0,0))
## [1] 12756274
```

Comment: It should be noted that this function doesn't account for depth.  Do you have a recommendation?

Comment: @DonScott yes it does, it calculates the straight line distance between two points of the form `c(lat, lon, height)`. The height variable is the depth coordinate

Comment: Thanks @Chris, that's exactly right. I've added a comment above the "sanity check" example that should clarify that that's so, and that depths should be entered (in meters) as "negative heights".

Answer (score 0):

You can use Matlab function ecefOffset to compute distance between two geographical locations in 3D.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/ecefoffset.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).